# Running R script in VBA using Shell

Tags: r, vba

VBA code is running, but it is not saving files from R output (Write.CSV files)

```
Sub R_Click()
   runs an external R code through Shell
   Dim shell As Object
   Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
   Dim style As Integer: style = 1
   Dim errorCode As Integer
   Dim path As String
   path = """" & "C:\Users\a.af.jain\Documents\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\RScript" & """ """ & "C:\Users\a.af.jain\Desktop\Missing_data.R" & """"
   errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

R Code

```
setwd("C:/Users/a.af.jain/Desktop/R")
input_missing = read.csv("input_missing.csv") 
Input_LGD = read.csv("Insert_LGD.csv") 
Result_data_missing = merge(input_missing,Input_LGD,all.x = TRUE) 
write.csv(Result_data_missing,"Result_data_missing.csv")
```

VBA is able to read input_missing file from R, But i don't know that whether it is doing merge or not and VBA code is not able to save files from R(write.csv file)

Comment: Is the R script should create output csv files? or VBA? If VBA needs to create .csv files then where is the code to create those .csv files. If R script needs to create then is the script creates the output when you run it from commandline?

Comment: Please give a [mcve], including the script that you are calling from R.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than post code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotation is off, you need to wrap the address of `Rscript` by double quotations and leave one space character between the `Rscript` address and the address of the R file that should be executed:

```
path = """C:\Users\a.af.jain\Documents\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\RScript"" C:\Users\a.af.jain\Desktop\Missing_data.R"
```

or

```
path = """C:\Users\a.af.jain\Documents\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\RScript""" & " " &  "C:\Users\a.af.jain\Desktop\Missing_data.R"
```